# Laravel - Extending the validation library

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I was wondering if someone could help me out.

Im writing a small application that allows people to signup for membership.

I have a plan which is paid.

I use the in build validation library to validate the name and password, but how can i extend that to validate credit card details the same way.

For example

```
$rules = array(
    'cardnumber' => 'required|legitcardnum'
);
```

So i can use it with the inbuilt library?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,

Comment: Have you tried using one of the readily available libraries that can do this for you? [Such as this one here](https://github.com/Intervention/validation)

Comment: @Ohgodwhy ... No i havent, i have never heard of it before ... Thank for that, i guess testing the expiry date will just be to make sure its sometime in the future?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy .. When i add isCreditcard to the rules, i get a message saying that validate isCreditcard doesnt exist

Comment: Sorry, my bad .... It was creditcard instead of isCreditcard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can register a custom validation rule:

```
Validator::extend('legitcardnum', function($attribute, $value, $parameters) {
    // Maybe you need to use preg_match($pattern, $value)
    if($value == 'cardnumber') return true;
    return false;
});
```

You may also use a custom message:

```
$messages = array(
    'cardnumber.legitcardnum' => 'Invalid card number!',
);
```

Then you may use it:

```
$rules = array(
    'cardnumber' => 'required|legitcardnum'
);
```

Validate it like:

```
$input = ...;
$rules = ...;
$validator = Validator::make($input, $rules, $messages);
```

You may also extend the `Validator` class and better to do it if you want to use that custom rule more than one place/controllers/classes in your projects. [Read more here](http://laravel.com/docs/validation#custom-validation-rules). Also check `PHP`'s [preg_match](https://www.php.net/preg_match) function.